# Verificar se alguma linha do resultado Select no Mysql contem um valor

Tags: mysql, select, where

Gostaria de saber como que se faz para verificar na cláusula where se alguma das linha tem um determinado numero. Por exemplo:
Se um select retornar

```
1
2
3
4
```

e na cláusula pedir o 4 ele retorna os valores, caso retorne

```
1
2
3
```

e na cláusula pedir o 4 ele retorna vazio.

Não sei se ficou claro, se houver duvida eu reescrevo a pergunta. Grato desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se entendi bem julgo que o uso da cláusula *EXISTS* faz o que pretende.
A *query* seria qualquer coisa assim:

```
SELECT numero FROM numeros WHERE EXISTS(SELECT numero FROM numeros WHERE numero = 4)
```

*EXISTS* retorna `true` se a *subquery* retornar alguma linha.

Se se existir o número 4 na tabela *EXISTS* retorna `true` fazendo com que a *query* retorne os números.
Caso contrário *EXISTS* retorna `false` e a *query* retornará zero linhas

Veja a funcionar no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0acde/1)

Comment: Era isso mesmo, e ficou muito simples. Muito Obrigado.